# didSelectRowAtIndexPath of custom UITableViewController never gets called

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm currently working on an iOS project and I'm quite new to it.

1. Description of my Problem:
   I made up my own TableView (derivation of UITableViewController that contains an UITableView). Unfortunately the method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" gets never called. Still I can scroll the TableView - I just can't select a row!
2. Description of my project(-structure):

   `MyAppDelegate` - contains `MyWindow`

   `MyWindow` - uses `MyRootViewController`

   `MyRootViewController` - contains `MyFirstViewController`

   `MyRootViewController` - contains `MySecondViewController`

   `MyFirstViewController` - contains just a view and some Buttons and Labels as starting view.

   `MyFirstViewController` - implements `ViewMediator`

   `MySecondViewController` - contains `MyTableViewController`

   `MySecondViewController` - implements `ViewMediator`

   `ViewMediator` - a protocol to let the views communicate without knowing each other

   `MyTableViewController` - derives from `UITableViewController`

   `MyTableViewController` - contains a `UITableView` (made in the constructor)

   `MyTableViewController` - overrides `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (this works, so the elements are  shown)

   `MyTableViewController` - overrides `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` (is never called)

   `MyTableViewController` - contains `MyTableViewModel`

   `MyTableViewModel` - just a class to read a file and load data into the `TableView`
3. What I already tried:

   - 3.1 Set "MyTableViewController" as delegate for the containing UITableView manually - even this should be done automatically.
   - 3.2 Made the UITableView outside of "MyTableViewController" and later set it to "MyTableViewController.view" and/or "MyTableViewController.tableView".
   - 3.3 I manually enabled UserInteraction in the UITableView. Thought this couldn't really be the problem, since scrolling works fine.

Funny fact: It worked before, I just added minor changes to the communication of the ViewControllers. Before they were communication directly (one-way), now they communicate by a mediator (two-ways) - the well-known mediator pattern. This should not affect the view and its controller, right?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Edit your question to include your `tableView:didSelectorRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: "MyTableViewController - derives from TableViewController" - but from where is `TableViewController` derived? Did you mean perhaps `UITableViewController`? - If so, just edit your question.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I meant the `UITableViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides designating the table view controller as the delegate of your table view, it is also required that the `view` property of your view controller is exactly your tableView.

If you want to have a separate view and a table view as a subview of that (allowing other subviews) you will have to subclass `UIViewController` rather than `UITableViewController`.

Comment: Ok, I did:

`MyTableViewController.view = myTableView`
`MyTableViewController.tableView = myTableView`

Doesn't make a difference, but thanks.

Comment: Make sure the delegate and datasource are set correctly. If it is a UITableViewController, setting the view is not necessary.